# UnitConvert bar <-> Pa

Tags: units

I wanted to use the following unit

```
cMax = Quantity[6.8221*^-9, "L/s/bar"];
```

But when calculating with it, I recognised there is some strange behaviour.
So I tried to convert it to L/s/Pa

```
cMax = Quantity[6.8221*^-9, "L/s/bar"]
UnitConvert[%, "L/s/Pa"]
```

[image]

So why do I get the unit `IndependentUnit[bars difference]`?

I also tried "Liters/Bars/Seconds", "L/s/Bars", "L/s/Bar", ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha had trouble interpreting your first unit and gave `"bar"` as `IndependentUnit["bars difference"]`, i.e. it did not know it was pressure.

You can use the proper syntax and WA will not need to be called:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[6.8221*^-9, "Liters"/("Bars" "Seconds")], "L/s/Pa"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[6.8221*10^-14, "Liters"/("Pascals" "Seconds")]
> ```

I found the proper syntax by evaluating each unit separately:

```
FullForm /@ {Quantity[1, "L"], Quantity[1, "s"], Quantity[1, "bar"]}
```

> ```
> {Quantity[1, "Liters"], Quantity[1, "Seconds"], Quantity[1, "Bars"]}
> ```

Comment: The tip with `FullForm` was exactly what I needed. I often had such a Problem and never knew how to get the exact form for the unit.